# Java web service custom return type

Tags: java, web-services, string, enums, return

I have this dilemma.

I'm developing a web services.
It has to return a list of supported languages.
Languages are stored in an enum.

Is it better to return (from web method) an enum array or covert it to string and return a string array.

Maybe I'd prefer string array so the client doesn't have to mess with custom object types, and no serialization/deserialization is required. But on the other hand, if I need that enum on the client I'll have to reimplement it and convert the string array back to enum array.

What do you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the thumb rule should be Keep It As Simple As Possible . Because i have seen really funny things happen with WSDLs while generating their clients.

Comment: Can you elaborate? I'm using jax-ws 2.1 and have never had any problems when generating a client.

Comment: I have seen auto generation in axis2 creating invalid classes when simpleTypes are used in a wsdl. Jax-WS is usually more cleaner and better then axis 2

Answer (score 1):

As usual: it depends :)

You have already answered your own question I'd say.. 
Does the client need the custom object in order to do any operations with it? Implement it with a custom object.

Is the String representation sufficient? Go for that..

I don't know of any guidelines regarding that topic..

Answer (score 1):

I agree. I believe services should be encapsulated and independent as much as possible. Anyway I'm not a big fan of any kind of auto-generation. Also I prefer REST and pure HTTP over WS and SOAP. Although I will leave both options available.

So I think I'll just stay with simple string array return. At least if nobody gives me a strong argument not to :)